# How do i cyclically trigger a variable to different values during certain simulation time values (like

Tags: matlab, simulink

```
function [Li_current] = light_influent [SimulationTime] 
switch flag_light
        case 0
            %Light intensity is set to a constant value for the whole simulation
            Li_current= pKt.Li
        case 1
             %Light intensity periodically alternates between 'on' at a set value or 'off'
             get_param (MyModel, SimulationTime)
```

Comment: i edited so your code would be readable, but you need to add some more text before it to explain what you are trying to do, what so you mean by simulation and supply a minimal example.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was confused when it came out the way that it did. Its a little tough to explain using a small example, but I'm running a simulation on simulink that models some differential rate equations of reaction rates based on several parameters, one of which is the light that is going into the reaction mixture. What i want to be able to do is have several configurations for light coming in. So if i use 'mode 0' of the configuration, it will have the light on at a constant value over the whole simulation time and more importantly, i want to create a 'mode 1' for light that goes off and on

Comment: within the simulation periodically as i choose. So let's say within a simulation time of 200 (measured here in hours), i want the light to be on for 12 hours and then off for 12 hours or for light to be on for 16 and then off for 8 etc.

Answer (score 0):

The trick here would be to use persistent variables. Basically, you need to keep track of the last time the light was switched on, and whether the light was on or off. Here is a minimum working example which will switch the light on and off every second

```
function [Li_current] = light_influent(SimulationTime)

% Declare and initialize the persistent variable during the first run
persistent lastTime
persistent lightOn
if isempty(lastTime)
    lastTime = SimulationTime; 
end
if isempty(lightOn)
    % Start with the light off
    lightOn = false; 
end
disp([ lastTime, SimulationTime, lightOn ] )

% Declared here for testing purposes...
flag_light = 1;
switch flag_light
case 0
    %Light intensity is set to a constant value for the whole simulation
    Li_current = 1;
case 1
     %Light intensity periodically alternates between 'on' at a set value or 'off'
     % Switch every one second. 
     switchFrequency = 1;
     if (SimulationTime - lastTime) > switchFrequency
         % If the light is on, turn it off. If off, turn it on
         lightOn = ~lightOn;
         lastTime = SimulationTime;
         disp('switched')
     end
     if lightOn
         Li_current = 1;
     else
         Li_current = 0;
     end
end
```

Comment: This was dumb of me. You should use the modulo function, not persistent variables for this application